# php code coverage on request execution

Tags: php, migration

I am working on a PHP migration project which is very complex and huge .

I want to know is there any tool which help me to see line of codes got executed when one page is rendered on the browser. This will help me to find codes in use and check business logics & migrate the one required.

Like code coverage report help us in unit test. Is there something available to know code executed when a particular request executed.

Comment: I'm interested in an answer from someone more experienced, but perhaps we can look into this for now:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Debug backtrace provides only stack trace for the place where that function is called. It's not helpful to analyze code coverage.

Comment: This tweet https://twitter.com/MrDanack/status/1146829199132581888 mentions https://github.com/matthiasnoback/live-code-coverage and https://github.com/krakjoe/pcov.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable XDebug profiler you can use that to get code coverage data and use that later to identify unused code. Please find more details here: http://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage

If you need to get that formatted in a nicer way you can use PHP-Code-Coverage lib that PHPUnit is using to generate the reports. You can find an example how to us it here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage